# Reading rtf information from entity entries to NSString

Tags: objective-c, rtf, binary-data

I have an entity (named Song) that one of the Attributes is binary data (a rtf field) that I use to to store chord charts or notes about a song. I need to be able to print this field along with the other string fields of this entity. I have tried every permutation of this I can think of:

```
NSAttributedString* myDataTry = [[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithRTF:myData documentAttributes:NULL]autorelease];
```

When I run this through the debuger the summary for myDataTry reads "out of scope" until the next line break and then myDataTry reads nil.

What do I need to change to make this thing go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what worked:

```
NSString *aStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:myData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        NSRange r = [aStr rangeOfString:@"{"];
        NSString *newAStr = [aStr substringFromIndex:r.location];
        NSData *newMyData;
        newMyData = [newAStr dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:1];
        NSAttributedString* myDataTry = [[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithRTF:newMyData documentAttributes:NULL]autorelease];
```

Now to insert that into the window with everything else!  Thanks for your point in the right direction @ShaggyFrog

Answer (score 1):

The reference for [initWithRTF:documentAttributes:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAttributedString_AppKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSAttributedString/initWithRTF%3adocumentAttributes%3a) reads:

> Returns an initialized object, or nil if rtfData can’t be decoded.

Are you absolutely certain that your RTF data can be decoded?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure...here is what is returned:   typedstreamè@
NSMutableDataNSDataNSObjecti[276c]{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf949\cocoasubrtf540
{\fonttbl\f0\fnil\fcharset0 LucidaGrande;}
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}
\pard\tx560\tx1120\tx1680\tx2240\tx2800\tx3360\tx3920\tx4480\tx5040\tx5600\tx6160\tx6720\ql\qnatural\pardirnatural

\f0\fs20 \cf0 step one text}

Comment: I looked up the rtf format convention and found that the stuff prior to the "{" was garbage.  So I converted the data to a string removed the garbage at the front and now I'm attempting to convert it back to data and read the rtf stuff.